# Set cell width of a Datagrid in a c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, width

I have a datagrid in my c# windows application and my code is

```
private void BindGrid(SmsPdu pdu)
 {
   DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
   SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
   dr[0]=data.OriginatingAddress.ToString();
   dr[1]=data.SCTimestamp.ToString();
   dr[2]=data.UserDataText;
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   dataGrid1.DataSource=dt;
  }
```

And my datagrid looks like this
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c368f82e0e.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c368f82e0e.jpg)

- How to set width of all three columns
  sender,time,Message?

Comment: I have modified the answer to include some code. Post your comment underneath it for me to know, if it was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simple way: use autosize

otherwise, use the Columns collection to set the size of each column

ADDENDUM:

sorry, I assumed you were using DataGridView, since it replaced DataGrid in .NET 2.0

for DataGrid, it's a little more complex - but google knows all!

http://www.syncfusion.com/faq/windowsforms/search/1004.aspx

Comment: @[Pandiya Chendur]: see addendum

Comment: @[Pandiya Chendur]: edit your question to post what you've tried, and I'll see what I can do. Is DataGridView not an option? It's much easier to work with than DataGrid...

Answer (score 0):

There is a Width property on the Columns collection:

DataGridView1.Columns(X).Width = Y

Where X is the name or index of the column and Y is the width

Comment: @rip its is datagrid not a datagridview

Answer (score 0):

<strike>How about [`datagrid1.Columns[0].Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx)?</strike>

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.aspx) class. It has a width property that you can set.

EDIT: Look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.aspx). And look at the code under `AddGridStyle`, which shows how to create the mapping & set each of the column style, width etc.

Hope that helps.

EDIT2: I am writing the following code without compiler (just using reflector & MSDN to look at the documentation). So, please be kind

```
DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = dataGrid1.TableStyles[0];
GridColumnStylesCollection colStyles = tableStyle.GridColumnStyles[0];

DataGridColumnStyle styleForCol1 = colStyles[0];
styleForCol1.Width = 165;

DataGridColumnStyle styleForCol2 = colStyles[1];
styleForCol1.Width = 125;
```

The code is derived from what I understood from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.aspx) page under **Remarks** , which is quoted below

> The System.Windows.Forms..::.DataGrid
>   control automatically creates a
>   collection of DataGridColumnStyle
>   objects for you when you set the
>   DataSource property to an appropriate
>   data source. The objects created
>   actually are instances of one of the
>   following classes that inherit from
>   DataGridColumnStyle:
>   DataGridBoolColumn or
>   DataGridTextBoxColumn class.